# How to move the mouse in JDK 10? .mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, click, mouse

I was trying to position the mouse and simulate a click with `Robot` but it seems like that is no longer supported in JDK 10. It looks like [this](https://ibb.co/cYwdLT) and says `The field InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK is deprecated since version 9`.

Does anybody know a way to fix this or how to simulate a click in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress(int)):

> However, it is recommended to use `InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK`, `InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK`, `InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK` instead.

So `InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK` is probably what you're looking for.

I believe the change is partly due to Java now supporting mice with more than three buttons.

**Note**: Remember to also call `mouseRelease` to be sure that the click is registered.